# html add multiple image links

Tags: html, powershell, dreamweaver

I have been working with Dreamweaver CC and have built a jssor image gallery biased off off [this one](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html) and it looks to be working good. but now I am trying to add all of the images and thumbnails to each gallery and can not find a good way to add them in mass. All of the images and thumbnails are in a numbered sequence in separate folders. example below.

```html
<div>
    <img u="image" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/_MG_0870_1001.JPG" />
    <img u="thumb" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/_MG_0870_1001.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    <img u="image" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/_MG_0886_1002.JPG" />
    <img u="thumb" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/_MG_0886_1002.jpg" />
</div>
```

I could not find a way to do it in Dreamweaver so tried to write something up in PowerShell and I can get close but not all the ways to no avail.

```PowerShell
$images = Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\Personal\Images\Gallery\1\image\"
$thumb_bnw = Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\Personal\Images\Gallery\1\thumb_BnW\"

# enumerate the items array
ForEach ($item in $images)
{
$img=$item.Name
            Write-Host "<div>"
            Write-Host $img

Foreach ($thumb_b in $thumb_bnw)
{
$bnw=$thumb_b.Name



            Write-Host $bnw
            Write-Host "</div>"


      }
      }
```

Comment: Your string concatenation seems to be writing invalid code. What does the script outputs? Your example code could use a little tidy up...

Answer (score 0):

Example;
Please write current directory images (../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/) and (../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/)

```
<?php
$image = glob('../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/*.jpg');
$thumb = glob('../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/*.jpg');

$image = array_chunk($image, 1);
$thumb = array_chunk($thumb, 1);

foreach ($image as $key => $img) {

        echo '<div>
        <img u="image" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/'.$img[0].'" />
        <img u="thumb" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/'.$thumb[$key][0].'" />
        </div>';

}
?>
```

Sory, my English not good.

Comment: when I try this 'code'( $img) { echo '
  
'; } ?> ) 'code' is what I see rendered on the page. Page still has a html extension would I need to change page extension?

Comment: Sory. I understand PHP code. You guys want Dreamweaver code. 
I saw afterwards.

Comment: php is fine just have never really worked with it much. thank you for your help. I just dont know how to make it work in the page? do I need to add anything to the header? change page extion from .html to .PHP?

Comment: **.html** extension to **.php** extension file. Save code. Example: **image.php** and run **http://localhost/image.php** web browser.

Answer (score 0):

So you are just trying to automate creating some html code. First thing is that the file names appear to be the same for both so why bother gathering that data again in a second loop. Also we can use a here-string to help with the formatting.

```
$template = @"
<div>
    <img u="image" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/{0}" />
    <img u="thumb" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/{0}" />
</div>
"@

$imagePath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"
Get-ChildItem $imagePath -Filter "*.jpg" | ForEach-Object{
    $template -f $_.Name
}
```

This will spit out formatted html code where the file names are inserted in the proper location.

```
<div>
    <img u="image" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/Penguins.jpg" />
    <img u="thumb" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/Penguins.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    <img u="image" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/image/Tulips.jpg" />
    <img u="thumb" src="../../Images/Gallery/Engagement/thumb_BnW/Tulips.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This Does seem to work!, I had planned to change the names to something like IMG_001 and thumb_BnW_001 but beagers can be chooers. Thanks